# willSendRequest redirectResponse doesn't work in iPhone SDK2.0

Tags: iphone, redirect

I use the delegate method connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse: in SDK 2.2, the code like below:

```
 - (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)con willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
 if(redirectResponse) {
  if(!self.autoRedirect) {
  NSLog(@"response will redirect");

   request = nil; 

  }
 }
 return request;
```

if the request is returned to nil ,it seems it hangs up here, and  delegate didReceiveData will not get called.

**but it works in SDK 3.**

Any suggestions about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the request parameter is pass by reference, so if you change it, you will get the response with the change you did.

Comment: thanks. after cheking the source code, I think it need to rewrite it